# Adjusted the canvas scaler in 1 level and now the camera in every scene is changed

Tags: unity, ui-design

I was attempting to add UI overlay to my game in 1 scene (to test run it) and wanted to scale it correctly so i went to Canvas scaler and changed it to Scale with Screen size, and then suddenly my screen size in play mode got very very zoomed in so i reverted the changes. I moved it back out and that fixed it but now it seems the camera is at a completely different ratio, even after turning off the canvas. Even though i only changed it in 1 scene it has changed this for my entire game, this has made the main menu buttons unusable as well for some reason, making the game unplayable

Any help would be hugely appreciated as i worry i wont get the game fixed before the game jam im participating in is over. Thanks!

**Update**

Here is a screesnshot of the canvas, i changed Canvas Scaler UI Scale Model to Scale with Screen Size and then it said 800x600 and i changed it to 1920x1080 and then it appeared to break so i changed it back to overlay but it did nothing

[image]

Here is the camera screenshot

[image]

Below is also showing the new black bars around the game, where it would have been full screen before

[image]

This was also only for 1 scene and the effects went across every camera for some reason, and it affects the build as well

Comment: Can you show us screenshots of what you're seeing in the editor? Does the problem also manifest in a published build?

Comment: @DMGregory Included screenshots in update. Yes it also affects the build. Due to it breaking the main menu buttons i couldnt get past the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Well i just feel very dumb now. I was looking for a setting in the inpsector somewhere when all i had really changed was the aspect ratio in the game tab. As for the buttons, I had forgotten that I had added in an image on the main menu right before this problem and the transparent part was overlapping with the button and i went to the image and turned off Raycast Target, and now the images work. Big hullabooloo for nothing haha